# TypeError: Unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference only On IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, typeerror

I AngularJS v1.2.0. I am getting following error only on IE11.

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function (/Scripts/angular.js:3850:11) at forEach (/Scripts/angular.js:303:9) at enter (/Scripts/angular.js:3849:9) at Anonymous function (/Scripts/angular.js:18725:17) at publicLinkFn (/Scripts/angular.js:5420:29) at ngRepeatAction (/Scripts/angular.js:18723:15) at $watchCollectionAction (/Scripts/angular.js:11299:11) at Scope.prototype.$digest (/Scripts/angular.js:11395:21) at Scope.prototype.$apply (/Scripts/angular.js:11634:13) at done (/Scripts/angular.js:7635:34)

It works fine on Firefox. It fails when following custom directives executes.

```
.directive('appMyCourseCards', ['$compile', '$log', function ($compile, $log) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {

    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {            
        var content = '<div class="well well-sm bottomSmallMargin" ng-repeat="schedule in studentSubjectSchedules | filterCourses:\'' + attributes.termperiodparingids + '\' ">' +
                            '<div class="row">' +                                    
                                        '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                                            '<div class="pull-left">{{schedule.SSECName}}</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +                                                                            
                            '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

        element.append($compile(content)(scope.$parent));
    }
};
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same screnario...

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the details of your custom filter 'filterCourses'?

I created this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Afw4VJynLf65eRtzEAvl?p=preview) with most of your code and it works ok in IE11, so I suspect it may be the filter that is causing the issue.
This is what I have in Plunker

```
    .directive('appMyCourseCards', ['$compile', '$log', function ($compile, $log) {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {

    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {   
      scope.$parent.studentSubjectSchedules = [{SSECName: "name1"}, {SSECName: "name2"}];
        var content = '<div class="well well-sm bottomSmallMargin" ng-repeat="schedule in studentSubjectSchedules " >' +
                            '<div class="row">' +                                    
                                        '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                                            '<div class="pull-left">{{schedule.SSECName}}</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +                                                                            
                            '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

        element.append($compile(content)(scope.$parent));
    }
}}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  It seems this issue appears after a multiple post back. In my application, I am using angular model, which updated by controller when a drop down value changed by the user, then the directives use that model. It works fine in 1st time load, but in multiple post back this issue appears.